# Connect Android Emulator to local network

Tags: android, windows-8.1, emulation

Does anyone know how can I connect my android emulator to my local host network. I am trying to test web services. I can test services in my local host using 10.0.2.2 but I cannot test a local server in my host network. I have searched all day yesterday and today with no good results. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator could not reach the server because the sever had multiple bindings/sites so the IP would not work. The emulator can reach any IP address that is available on the localhost as long is a server with one site service. Another issue since the emulator's IP starts with 10... it was causing problems with the local DNS since it also starts with 10... The quick fix we added a wild card to the IIS on the server and that allow the emulator to test the service. Hope this helps other developers.